# Windows/Linux text rendering

Tags: windows, linux

I just noticed that Windows renders text differently than Linux.

[image: win-linux-text]

Why is that and what's the purpose of orange and blue "shadows"?

Comment: Linux can be configured to look like Windows, with `<fontconfig><match target="font"><edit name="rgba" mode="assign"><const>rgb</const></edit></match></fontconfig>`

Comment: Good question and good answers, but as stated and answered not really a programming topic...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows ClearType (also an option on Linux and Mac) optimises for LCD displays which have subpixels in an RGB layout to increase the horizontal resolution thrice-fold. Hence you end up with orange/blue "thin pixels" to enhance the rendering of the text where necessary. They're not shadows, but look funny when zoomed in. They're using a trick of the display medium to enhance text rendering resolution.

It looks like your Linux set up is currently set up with standard anti-aliasing, which is better for CRT displays, and where you want to smooth text in both directions. It also looks good on high DPI displays where ClearType gets less relevant.

Answer (score 2):

The article on wikipedia about [Subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) might interest you, about that, I suppose.

And, about windows, you can take a look on the [ClearType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType) one.

Answer (score 0):

Where did these samples come from? It appears to just be a different choice in how the font anti-aliasing was done.

Comment: The ubuntu sample is from a virtual machine.

Comment: sorry, which application on the VM?

Comment: Firefox in both cases